# Powershell script to Check and keep program running

Tags: powershell

Making a short script to keep a program that crashes every now and then running,

Here is what I am trying and been editing

```
$date = Get-Date -Format G

Function Loop {
{ if(Get-Process -Name notepad -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null
 write-host -ForegroundColor red "Server Is Not Running" 
 .\eldorado.exe -launcher -dedicated -headless -window -height 300 -width 300 
 echo "Guardian Started Headless Eldorito Server $($date)" | Add-Content .\dedicatedServer.log }



 else {write-host -ForegroundColor green "Server Is Running"  
       sleep 10  
       Loop
       }
       Loop
}
```

What am I doing wrong? / New to scripting / programming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing a mash of code, or not copy and pasting properly?

```
$date = Get-Date -Format G   # OK

Function Loop {          # OK 

# no, your function now starts with a scriptblock
# no, your if () {} pattern is broken. 
{if(Get-Process -Name notepad -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null


# ok, but formatting makes it hard to read
 write-host -ForegroundColor red "Server Is Not Running" 
 .\eldorado.exe -launcher -dedicated -headless -window -height 300 -width 300 
 echo "Guardian Started Headless Eldorito Server $($date)" | Add-Content .\dedicatedServer.log }


#ok
 else {write-host -ForegroundColor green "Server Is Running"  
       sleep 10  
# not ok, your loop is now a recursive function call which will consumer more resources forever until it crashes

       Loop
       }

       # what's this doing?
       Loop
}
```

It doesn't seem like you need a function at all, just a loop..

->

```
$date = Get-Date -Format G

while ($true)
{
    if ((Get-Process -Name notepad -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null)
    {

        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Server Is Not Running"
        .\eldorado.exe -launcher -dedicated -headless -window -height 300 -width 300
        "Guardian Started Headless Eldorito Server $($date)" | Add-Content .\dedicatedServer.log 

    }
    else
    {
        write-host -ForegroundColor Green "Server Is Running"
    }

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
}
```